# display next image on drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three div boxes with id 10, 11, 12. I have an image array, on dropping an item box, the box element gets deleted, I make a call to function nextslide in the on-drop method which calls next slide to display.

On dropping the first element on any box with id 10, 11, 12 The box gets deleted, but displaying next image through nextslide() method doesn't work.

I want to display next image in an array on successfully dropping the first element.

How to achieve this?

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}


var x = document.get

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  alert(data);
  var el = document.getElementById(data);

  el.parentNode.removeChild(el); // deleting drag item

  ev.target.style.backgroundColor = 'initial'; //[value indicate which box elemenet] bgcoclor none


  nextslide();

}


var images = new Array();
images[0] = "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random";
images[1] = "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random";
images[2] = "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random";
var currentpic = 0;
var lastpic = images.length - 1;

function nextslide() {
  if (currentpic == lastpic) {
    currentpic = 0;
    document.getElementById('slide').src = images[currentpic];
  } else {
    currentpic++;
    document.getElementById('slide').src = images[currentpic];
  }
}
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: coral;
  width: 20%;
  height: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: -2px;
  border-radius: 12%;
  background-color: #00b300;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10">
    <p name="values"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="11">
    <p name="values"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="12">
    <p name="values"></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" draggable="true" id="slide" style="width:30px; height:100px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded" onclick="nextslide()" />
</div>
```